# Passing output arguments between functions, code not working

Tags: matlab, function, data-structures

I can't seem to pass a variable from one function to another. I've used functions quite extensively (but I'm still a programming newb), so I'm probably just making a dumb mistake here, but I can't for the life of me find it! This is what I'm doing.

My first function

```
function [ ToFparam ] = ToF_3D_Viewer( ToFparam, RGBparam, Naviparam, DICOMparam )
    ToF_2_DICOM_Coords(ToFparam,Naviparam,DICOMparam);
    disp(ToFparam.ROI.XYZ_DICOM); %says it's a non-existent field!
end
```

My second function

```
function [ ToFparam ] = ToF_2_DICOM_Coords( ToFparam, Naviparam, DICOMparam )
    Naviparam.Endotip_2_Tracker = diag([1,-1,-1,1]);
    [m,n,z]=size(ToFparam.ROI.XYZ);
    ToFparam.ROI.XYZ_DICOM=reshape(inv(Naviparam.data.Endo_RefHomMat(1:3,1:3))*inv(Naviparam.Endotip_2_Tracker(1:3,1:3))*(reshape(ToFparam.ROI.XYZ,[m*n z]))')',[m n z]);
    disp(ToFparam.ROI.XYZ_DICOM) %outputs correctly!
end
```

I also tried changing my first function to the following, but when I later try to add `ToFparam.ROI.XYZ_DICOM` to another matrix of the same size, which clearly outputs as a matrix in my `ToF_2_DICOM_Coords` function, it throws an error, saying I can't add a variable of type "structure"

```
function [ ToFparam ] = ToF_3D_Viewer( ToFparam, RGBparam, Naviparam, DICOMparam )
    ToFparam.ROI.XYZ_DICOM = ToF_2_DICOM_Coords(ToFparam,Naviparam,DICOMparam);
    disp(ToFparam.ROI.XYZ_DICOM); %says it's a non-existent field!
end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask for a return value in youre function call to `ToF_2_DICOM_Coords`,

```
function [ ToFparam ] = ToF_3D_Viewer( ToFparam, RGBparam, Naviparam, DICOMparam )
    Tofparam = ToF_2_DICOM_Coords(ToFparam,Naviparam,DICOMparam);
    disp(ToFparam.ROI.XYZ_DICOM); %says it's a non-existent field!
end
```

Comment: Thanks, knew it was something stupid like that =p. I think this question was asked and solved in record time